# Ember JS passing a parameter with insert-newline using TextField

Tags: ember.js

I have an input that I would like to fire an action when the user presses enter. I have been using `insert-newline="actionName"` to do this, however I need to pass a parameter to that action and everything I tried to do fails.

In my template I have tried the following lines:

```
{{focus-input value=keywords placeholder="Search Term" insert-newline="search searchTerm"}}

{{focus-input value=keywords placeholder="Search Term" insert-newline="search, searchTerm"}}

{{focus-input value=keywords placeholder="Search Term" insert-newline="{search, searchTerm}"}}

{{focus-input value=keywords placeholder="Search Term" insert-newline="{search searchTerm}"}}

{{focus-input value=keywords placeholder="Search Term" insert-newline="search(searchTerm)"}}
```

In my controller I have the action defined:

```
search: function (searchType) {
        var search = this;

        if (searchType != "all") {
            if (search.get('keywords') != "") {
                search.send('close');
                search.transitionToRoute('/search/' + searchType + "-" + search.get('keywords').underscore());
            } else {
                search.send('close');
            }
        } else {
            search.transitionToRoute('/');
        }
    }
```

and the following component:

```
Books.FocusInputComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({
   becomeFocused: function () {
        var becomeFocused = this;

        becomeFocused.$().focus();
    }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

I've looked around for an answer for this, but I can't find anything in regard to passing a parameter to an action using that inline insert-newline method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass in your controller into the component like this:

```
{{focus-input value=keywords placeholder="Search Term" searchControllerBinding="controller"}}
```

and then in your component have a `keypress()` handler to dispatch the search:

```
Books.FocusInputComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({
   becomeFocused: function () {
        var becomeFocused = this;

        becomeFocused.$().focus();
    }.on('didInsertElement'),

    keyPress: function() {
       this.get('searchController').search(this.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: I use focus-input for a number of other inputs as well that shouldn't have this functionality. That is why I didn't add anything to the component. I can try to create a new component and extend focusInputComponent I suppose

Comment: Yes, extending and adding this funcitonality to a new component would be a good idea